# Check for duplicate IDs?

Tags: html, ide, editor

I'm using a simple website CMS called *TidyCMS*.
It automatically gives an ID to every element made editable, like `tidyautoid-32`. 
However, this does not work so well and sometimes it makes duplicate IDs and modifying an element with an duplicate ID repeats the element on the website and does other unwanted things.

I've got 700 lines of HTML code, which I wouldn't want to manually review, and I couldn't remember all the numbers to review.

**How can I check for duplicate IDs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try copying and pasting your HTML code into the W3C HTML Validator ( https://validator.w3.org/ ) - this would flag where there are duplicate IDs within the HTML code and on which line they appear.